# AutoDelete shortcodes in post content

Tags: jquery, wordpress, function, shortcode

It's possible autodelete [shortcode] and content of shortcode in $content of post with a function? I want the Authors only will can put text, not code or shortcodes.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hook into **wp_insert_post_data**.

**PHP:**

```
function remove_shortcodes( $data , $postarr ){
    $data['post_content'] = strip_shortcodes( $data['post_content'] );
    return $data;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'remove_shortcodes', '99', 2 );
```

**References:**

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes